# Spring validates controller parameters after conversion. Can it validate before conversion?

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, data-binding, type-conversion

Say I have a class Dog with a field, numberOfLegs, validated to be 4 or less.

```
class Dog {

    @Max(4)
    int numberOfLegs;
}
```

This is a parameter to a controller method, and if validation fails, then Spring sends the relevant error message in the response.

However, the request actually sends up a DogRestDto.

```
class DogRestDto {

    @Max(4)
    int legs;
}
```

I use a converter to change this into a Dog for my controller to use, but the validation is done on Dog rather than DogRestDto, and the error message talks about `dog.numberOfLegs` rather than `dog.legs`.

Is there a simple way to tell Spring do the validation on the REST dto prior to conversion, so that the error message makes more sense to the client?

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this by overriding the mvcUriComponentsContributor method in my DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration to replace the RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor in the requestMappingHandlerAdapter's argumentResolvers with a implementation that validates the REST DTO. It obtains the REST DTO from a request-scoped bean that I've made to hold the source object currently being converted, which is populated by my implementation of the GenericConversionService.

It's not very pretty. I'd love it if Spring gave me a cleaner way to do this.